# Use Git to automate deployment to two hostings with two branches

Tags: git, version-control, web-deployment

Is it possible to achieve the following automated web deployment with git:

Server:

- GIT Repo with a master and a dev branch
- Hosting of `dev.mysite.com` (dev branch)
- Hosting of `mysite.com` (master branch)

Basically I want to develop on my local machine and then commit to the dev branch for a testing of the changes on the real server environment.
If everything is tested I'll merge the develop commits into the master / live site.
Commits/Merges should automatically copy the files into to the document root.

I have seen quite some tutorials on post-hooks, but I'm fairly new into Git and don't really know how to achieve this.

### Additional Info

The hostings are sandboxed and the user assigned to the hosting (`dev.mysite.com` & `mysite.com`) has no access to the files of the other hosting. Read: Everything should probably happen via git hooks as I can't move files to the directory of the other hosting.
Also I don't want to ssh manually into the server to pull changes into the according hosting, as I'm not the only developer but the only one with ssh access and I don't want to be called every 5 minutes to pull new changes.

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly possible:

Detailed explanation at http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto

For you, you need to have a post-recieve hook on the server git repository which looks somewhat like this (pseudo script):

> #/bin/bash
> if push is to branch dev/
> GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/dev.mysite.com git checkout -f
> exit
> else if push is to branch master 
> GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/mysite.com git checkout -f

This might get you what you desire! :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! But does this work even if the git user does not have access to the paths of the web hostings?

Comment: No! In that case it wont! But that makes no sense! Why don't you control access at repo level. Or have two separate repos of devl and production? So every developer has push access to devl (Since it writes to dev.site.com and only selected few have push access to main prod)

Comment: I don't think that having two repos for the same project is a goal to have with Git and branches.
I'm using a managed server where each user is completely sandboxed from the other one.

Comment: @Adan0s In that case why don't you maintain a list of users who have access to push to master and you can write a pre-push and/or post-recieve hook that checks if the user is authorized and and then checksout the master code on prod-site